# Add a mean column to a table dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as:

```
   COL1 VALUE1 VALUE2
1   A,A      1      5
2 A,A,B      1      3
3     C      1      1
4     D      1      2
5     D      1      2
6   A,A      1     10
7 A,B,A      1      2
```

and I can succeed to remove duplicate within the COL1 and count the number of different duplicated in COL1 by using:

```
as.data.frame(table(tab$COL1)) %>%
  group_by(Var1 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(Var1), ","), function(x) toString(unique(x)))) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
```

And then I get:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Var1   Freq
  <chr> <int>
1 A         2
2 A, B      2
3 C         1
4 D         2
```

But I wondered if someone had an idea in order to add a new column called `Mean` which would be for each `COL1 groups`, the mean of the `VALUE2` values and then get:

```
  Var1      Freq  Mean 
1 A         2     7.5   < because (5+10)/2 =7.5
2 A, B      2     2.5   < because (3+2)/2 =2.5 
3 C         1     1     < because 1/1 = 1 
4 D         2     2     < because (2+2)/2 = 2
```

Here is the dataframe if it can helps:

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A,A", 
"A,A,B", "A,B,A", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), VALUE1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), VALUE2 = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Hi, I added comment on the expected output to explain how I get it, in fact I just do for each COL1 groups the mean of Value2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the frequency table directly in the dplyr chain, and then just add a `Mean = mean(VALUE2)` in the `summarise()` call.

I.e.

```r
tab %>%
    group_by(Var1 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(COL1), ","), function(x) toString(unique(x)))) %>%
    summarise(Freq = sum(VALUE1), Mean = mean(VALUE2))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Var1   Freq  Mean
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 A         2   7.5
# 2 A, B      2   2.5
# 3 C         1   1  
# 4 D         2   2
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
tab %>%
  mutate(COL1 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(COL1), ","), function(x) toString(unique(x)))) %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(VALUE1),
            Mean = mean(VALUE2))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  COL1   Freq  Mean
* <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A         2   7.5
2 A, B      2   2.5
3 C         1   1  
4 D         2   2
```

Comment: Beaten by 31 seconds!

Comment: Yeah too bad. But no prob.

Comment: I've upvoted yours because you had spotted the fact that OP wants the sum of VALUE1

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Comment: but still feel a little disappointed that OP accepted yours ;)

Comment: I can change if you want ^.^

Comment: Nooooooo, don't change it! XD

Comment: we should be able to accept several answers to thank the speakers ...

Comment: I yield to @Sam, he's still in his early SO career ;)

Comment: Vielen Dank @Chris :)